# I'm looking for a nice local ticketing system

Tags: project-management, ticket-system

I'm looking for a nice software to store tickets information locally. It should work only on my laptop under Linux, and be easily installed. The core features that I need:

- storing tickets
- allows to create additional documentation
- don't take too much ram
- very easy installation (I don't have whole days for configuring)
- multiproject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and it's fantastic for all of the above. It's browser based so you'd need to install and configure it but it's not hard and well worth the effort.

Redmine is quick efficient and it's the best tool of its kind that I've ever found and I've looked tried many.

I know little about ruby/rails and it took me a few hours to install from clean using the guides.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Project Kaiser](http://www.projectkaiser.com)

Answer (score 0):

How about a TidliDu http://www.giffmex.org/tiddlydu2.html. You can't make it easier to install. Create a new one for each project.

Answer (score -1):

OpenOffice spreadsheet?